# How to follow up with function only once data is downloaded

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to look for an answer in other posts but haven't been successful. I am trying to find a way to keep my code from processing until it downloads a certain piece of information (usd) from an external database.

For example:

```
class func getExchange() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let usd = json["USD"]["last"].float
            print("USD Exchange Rate is: \(usd!)")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(usd!, forKey: "currency")
            ViewController().reloadCurrency()
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In this block I need to get the value of "usd" before I run the function ViewController().reloadCurrency()

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's not working about your above code? Looks like you _are_ getting the value of "usd" before running reloadCurrency().

Comment: Maybe you've identified the wrong problem here? What looks strange to me here is that you're calling reloadCurrency() on a newly initialized ViewController which you then do nothing with.

Comment: The problem is that usd is downloaded from an external database, so the function ViewController().reloadCurrency() is being called while the download hasn't finished and the value of usd is still nil. Just edited the post a little bit to make it more legible.

Comment: The success block will only be executed after the request returns a response. The error may be with your parsing of the response JSON. please check the response

Comment: So far its giving me an error due to the fact that the value is still nil when the function is called. In fact, the function is called, and only a few seconds after, the print command is shown on my console.

Comment: @prolfe has the answer - you are instantiating a new view controller rather than executing the method on your current view controller (`self`?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Really I don't understand your question. When code run to return block in

> Alamofire.request

it 's mean downloading finished
Whatever,try:

```
     static func getExchange(handleComplete:(dataReturn:AnyObject?)->()) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).validate().responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let usd = json["USD"]["last"].float
            print("USD Exchange Rate is: \(usd!)")
            handleComplete(dataReturn: usd)
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

and using:

```
       Until.getExchange { (dataReturn) -> () in
            if let data = dataReturn as? typeOfData{
                // do s.t
                //ex : 
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(usd!, forKey: "currency")
                ViewController().reloadCurrency()
            }
        }
```

Comment: This still has the same problem - calling `reloadCurrency` on a new view controller instance

Comment: waooo, i wrote "ex:" , if you don't understand , it 's "example". if want you can change it = self.reloadCurrency()

Comment: Yes, but you are missing the essential cause of their problem.  Changing an instance method to a class method won't help if they still call the reload code on the wrong instance of their view controller

Comment: This is a separate class from the ViewController that updates the information. I am declaring the function here, but the reloadCurrency function happens in ViewController. Does that clarify @Paulw11 ?

Comment: @NguyenHoan the command 'Until' is giving me error 'Expected Declaration' so I haven't been able to try your solution.

Comment: Ok.  You can't simply allocate a *new* instance of `ViewController` - you need to pass your existing view controller instance to this method.  Typically you would pass a completion closure to this method and have the completion closure in `getExchange` invoke the completion closure that was passed.  In that closure you would call `self.reloadCurrency`.  Also using `NSUserDefaults` as your data model is kind of evil.  You can define the completion closure to accept the currency value as an argument

Comment: @Jacobo Koenig Until is your class which contains getExchange function

Comment: Thanks @NguyenHoan that worked!! How can I edit my question to help people understand it better in the future?

Comment: :D so fun when it 's useful . "How can I edit my question to help people understand it better in the future?" ==> it 's difficult for me because my english is very bad

Comment: and you can vote for my answer to other people know: it 's ok :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of asynchronous programming is a bit hard go grasp at first. What happens is that your closure (or block) actually is executed in the background. So to get the data in the primary thread you have to go to that by `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  }`
In your case it should look like this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  
    print("USD Exchange Rate is: \(usd!)")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setFloat(usd!, forKey: "currency")
    ViewController().reloadCurrency()
    self.handleComplete(dataReturn: usd)
 }
```